# How can I remap arrows keys to other short cut?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I am a programmer, I need to use arrows keys a lot, so can I remap these keys to other keys?

I have downloaded the karabiner, however, I cannot define the complex modifications rules myself, karabiner only provide [default rules](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/#alternative_keyboard_layouts). Yet, I want some new rule, like arrow up can be triggered by fn + i.

Comment: You can also use Emacs shortcuts like `CTRL⌃` + `f`,`b`,`n`,`p` (right, left, down, up respectively)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, however, I prefer to use fn + j (left), fn + i (up), fn + l (right), fn + k (down).

Answer (score 1):

As you are a programmer you won't have any difficulty in editing Karabiner-Elements Complex Modifications yourself.

They are to be found at: `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json` and can even be edited or expanded with BBEdit (or TextEdit).
Here's an example how I configured my own arrow key(s):

```
{ "description": "Up_arrow to Page_up",
  "manipulators": [
                   { "from": { "key_code": "up_arrow",
                               "modifiers": {
                                     "mandatory": ["left_control"] }
                             },
                     "to":   [ { "key_code": "page_up" } ],
                     "type": "basic"
                            }
```

Here's the JSON Reference Manual: `https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/json.html`